# Improve core web vitals based on May 2021 google algorithm

Tags: wordpress, plugins, search-engine, google-search-console, core-web-vitals

We have wordpress website we are trying to reach core web vitals.

Our desktop page speed is 94 still we did not reach core web vitals

[image]

[image]

so please explain how to reach core web vitals this is very important to next May 2021 google releasing new algorithm.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to check out https://web.dev/debug-web-vitals-in-the-field/ ? That page explains how to use web APIs to collect CLS/FID/LCP for your analysis. With that data you can try to understand what happens on your page that leads to lower vitals scores.